# install artisan in an existing laravel app that has not been installed using composer

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, unique

I uploaded my laravel app to my hosting. Although I have artisan in the root directory but running `php artisan` or any other command will not work at all.

I found that if I install  a fresh copy of laravel in the hosting using composer 
artisan commands works fine.

How can I install artisan in an existing app.

Comment: What do you mean by "not work at all"?

Comment: the command line returns without any thing ...

Comment: Make sure `artisan` (the file) is executable. From the root of your project: `chmod +x artisan`. If your host doesn't allow you to change permissions, then you may be out of luck.

Comment: didn't work. I think the artisan depends on some scripts in the vendor folder

Comment: After you uploaded your app, did you `composer install`?